# Searching for values in the column of a csv file

Tags: c#, io

I have a csv file with 2 columns, `ID` and `Flag`.  There are lots of `Flag` values, but there are a few which denote bad things- errors, failures etc.  What I need to do is fairly straightforward- search the `Flag` column to see if any of those values are in the 'Bad Flags' group.

I have the following code that does what I need- checks if the flags file exists, iterates over each line, splits it  and then checks if that current line has an element for flag and then checks if the flag is in my bad group- if I find even one I am done:

```
private bool CheckFlagStatus( string directory )
{
    // Bad flags
    const int Flag1 = 1;
    const int Flag2 = 5; 
    const int Flag3 = 6;
    const int Flag4 = 42;
    const int Flag5 = 61;

    bool isGood = true;
    string flagFilePath= Path.Combine( directory, "flags.csv" );
    if ( File.Exists( flagFilePath) )
    {
        using ( StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( flagFilePath) )
        {
            string line;
            while ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( line = reader.ReadLine() ) )
            {
                var splitval = line.Split(',');
                if ( splitval.Length == 2 )
                {
                    var flagString = splitval[1];
                    int flag;
                    bool parsed = Int32.TryParse( flagString, out flag );
                    if ( parsed )
                    {
                        if ( flag == Flag1 || flag == Flag2 || flag == Flag3
                            || flag == Flag4 || flag == Flag5 )
                        {
                            isGood = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return isGood;
}
```

While this works, this is a very linear brute force approach.  While perfect with a flags.csv file with 20 lines, what would happen if there were a million?  I'm wondering what are some suggestions on how to make this more elegant or to optimize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already optimized. It would take longer if there were a million lines, but the performance is linear which is much better than most algorithms. You could make your code more elegant but that's just a matter of styling and has nothing to do with what you're actually doing or how optimal it is. Keep in mind, optimized code is typically more lengthy.

By doing something like `File.ReadLines` then splitting on a new line then splitting on a `,` then looping over the list only looking at odd indexes your code might be more elegant (fewer lines) but the performance would not be better. In fact, it would likely be worse.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is okay, it has to be like this to check every single line, I just try to make your code more readable by using LINQ and `Readlines` method:

```
private bool CheckFlagStatus(string directory)
{
    badFlags = new[] { 1, 5, 6, 42, 61};
    string flagFilePath = Path.Combine(directory, "flags.csv" );

    if (File.Exists(flagFilePath))
    {
        var lines = File.ReadLines(flagFilePath)
                        .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line));

        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            var splitval = line.Split(',');
            if (splitval.Length == 2)
            {
                var flagString = splitval.Last();
                int flag;

                if (int.TryParse(flagString, out flag))
                {
                    if (badFlags.Contains(flag)) return false;
                }
            }
        }    
    }
    return true;
}
```